# How to get Active Menu Item Highlighted in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

I have created CSS for highlighting color of Active Menu in Joomla, though the color change is working fine on hover, but the color does not change in of Active Menu

Any getaways !! *Note - we have one more site in Joomla 1.5 older version - there this code works fine as active menu color changes. **However issue coming in Joomla 2.5***

CSS

```
.bluetabs li a:visited{
color: #FFFFFF;
              }
.bluetabs li a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #FFFFFF;
background:#b60205;
text-decoration:none;
              }
.bluetabs li.selected{
background:#b60205;
padding:0;
             }
.bluetabs li.selected a{ /*selected main tab style */
 background:#b60205;
  border-bottom-color: white;
             }
 .bluetabs li.selected a:hover{ /*selected main tab style */
  text-decoration: none;
              }
```

This is the function wherein correctly defining selected menu too

```
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if(($lt+1) < $cnt ){
            $maincls = "";
        }else{
            $maincls = "last ";
        }
        if($parentid == $row->id){
            $class = $clsArray[$lt].'selected';
        }else{
            $class = $clsArray[$lt];
        }
    }
    $list.='</ul>';
}
echo $list;
//echo $list_sub;
    }
```

The site name is :- http://www.ecarloan.in
However, checked it through Firebug, its not taking up 'li class=selected' in the active menu, rather showing below :-

**Its not executing :-**

```
 <li class="selected">
```

rather showing, this code in active css for a sample active menu

```
<li class="item-101 current active">
<a href="/">Discussion Board</a>
</li>
```

The Entire Function Code is :-

```
foreach($rows as $row){
        if(($lt+1) < $cnt ){
            $maincls = "";
        }else{
            $maincls = "last ";
        }       
        if($parentid == $row->id){
            $class = $clsArray[$lt].'selected ';
        }else{
            $class = $clsArray[$lt];
        }
        if($vid!="" and $row->id==8){

        $list.=' <li class="'.$class.'"><a  href="dealer">Service</a></li>';
        }else{
        $list.=' <li class="'.$class.'"><a  href="'.mosGetLinkTop1($row).'">'.$row->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        }
    $list.='</ul>';
}
echo $list;
//echo $list_sub;
```

}

Comment: Do you have a live page that shows this behavior? My first guess would be that there is a space missing in the `'selected'` class addition in PHP (perhaps `$clsArray[$lt]` does not end with a space), but I, for one, cannot make much more of the code you provided.

Comment: MasterAm's analysis sounds pretty good. Inspect the page of output to see the class actually on the menu item.

Comment: Sure, the site name is www.ecarloan.in . Have added the function code too.

Comment: Well, that is an entirely different issue. Let's get your override execute first. What is the php file path? It should be `templates/<your template>/html/mod_menu/default.php`. I suspect that it is `mod_mainmenu`, which is what `J1.5` used. I do not know if they are compatible, though.

Answer (score 0):

What I believe to be your main issue is the change of `mod_mainmenu` to `mod_menu` in Joomla! 1.6+.

This causes your template override not to be executed.

You need to change its path to `templates/<your template>/html/mod_menu/default.php`.
Note that this will override all of the menus on your site, if you have more than one.

If you want to only override this menu, you can create a layout override, which you can selectively apply to components and modules. It is explained [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla).

Note that `mod_mainmenu` and `mod_menu` are not completely the same (e.g, the `current` id given to the current item has been changed to a `current` class to prevent w3c validation issues when more than one menu is displayed).

Therefore, you may need to slightly adjust your template override code.